# Java: Trying to ignore (or skip) a Carriage-Return(\n) that isn't an End-of-Line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, carriage-return, end-of-line

I successfully read in data from csv files with this code

```
            Scanner scanIt = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filef)));
            while (scanIt.hasNextLine())
            {
                String inputLine = scanIt.nextLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            scanIt.close();
```

until I encountered this line (in the file) which seems to have a "carriage return" buried within the read line, located between- ,"TBD and TBD",

> Incoming PR# & Doc#: ,"TBDTBD",,Funds Held By Sponsor/Unallocated
>   Funds,,,, $-   ,,,NS02 , $-   , $-   ,

I am trying to solve this problem by tell the code to look for a carriage return "\n" preceded by a comma "," as a true end of line

```
while (scanIt.hasNext(","+"\n"))
```

but that did not solve the problem.

What are ideas to resolve this problem?
Thank you for taking the time to do this.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Scanner as it's line separator pattern is hard coded as ```"\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]"``` (see ```Scanner.LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN```).
The problem that ```Scanner``` doesn't really understand the quotes around the string with the new-line.
You better use a more CSV library such as https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 2):

you need a CSV parser to properly read the file. The real solution is that a `\n` or `\r` in between `"` is not the end of a line.

Please use a proper CSV parser because this is not the only problem you will encounter. Data with a `,` could be another such problem. a CSV parser will solve all of these.